Как писать unit-тесты внутри самого тестируемого класса, или в другом классе, но в пределах одного кодового файла?
Слышал, что библиотека NUnit позволяет писать тесты таким способом (каким-то из двух названных). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это осуществить, сколько не пытался - не получается. При создании отдельного проекта для тестов всё работает. Есть подозрение что это как-то связано с тем, что при использовании отдельного проекта для тестов в него добавляется ссылка на тестируемый проект, а при написании тестов внутри тестируемого кодового файла ссылку добавлять не на кого (не на него же самого добавлять). Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?
P.S. О том, что не стоит объединять тесты и тестируемые проекты в один я знаю, это требуют в курсе, по которому я учусь - отправлять задание, и тесты на него в одном файле.

Тесты нужно писать в другом проекте! Ведь код, размещённый в одном проекте попадёт в одну сборку. А зачем пользователю приложение с тестами? Или зачем заливать на сервер сайт с тестами?

Хотя есть методология, где тестовая инфраструктура встроена в основной код. Но в строго-типизированном языке наподобие C# это выглядит сомнительно.

Ага, прочитал не только заголовок, но и тело вопроса. Вообще, проблем возникать не должно. Просто пишете код тестов в том же проекте, хоть в разных файлах, хоть в одном. Помечаете их атрибутами. TestAdapter именно по атрибутам найдёт их и будет запускать.

Спасибо за ответ! Можно чуть подробнее на счёт атрибутов? Вы про атрибуты типа [TestClass] и [TestMethod], или есть ещё какие-то? У меня по ощущениям всё упирается именно в ссылку. Ссылка есть - всё работает, ссылки нет - тесты не видят тестируемую сборку.

тесты разные бывают, и делятся на два типа: те что трогают объекты, и те что не трогают объекты; далее, сами тесты порождают объекты, а значит как либо изменяют реальную кучу, т.е. тесты собой влияют на кучу - например разрушают локальность, а значит такие тесты лживые, итд итп

Извините, не совсем понимаю как это относится к моему вопросу...

так а вам и не нужно [в данном] случае ничего понимать, потому что написано не вам; однако же т.к. вы пишете про то, что не понимаете про написанное - так что конкретно вы не понимаете? написано про объекты, объекты порождаются например н-юнитом, и как это происходит - не известно, хотя расковырять можно, и суть не в этом, добавленные н-юнитом "левые" объекты в кучу - влияют на кучу, а значит приведут к изменённой куче, а не той что была, а значит тестируется другая куча, а не то что была

и изначально написано про две глобальных группы тестов - те что собой НЕ влияют на кучу, и те что собой влияют на кучу - вот во втором случае тесты будут врать
